# Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation such that $W \subset V$ is an invariant subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation such that $W \subset V$ is an invariant subspace.

Prove that there exists $\lambda$ an eigenvalues of $T$ and $v\notin W$ such that $(T- \lambda I)v \in W$.

I have been stuck with this exercise for hours, I thought about using minimal polynomials or to think about Jordans's form because it's what I'm learning but it didn't help.

I would be glad if you can give me a hint or a direction how to solve.

Thank you!

Comment: When you wrote $(T- \lambda I)V \in W$, did you mean $(T- \lambda I)v\in W$?

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry, I edited it! Thank you

Comment: What way did you use the fact that $W$ is invariant under $T$?

Comment: You need the additional requirement that $V$ is finite-dimensional (or more generally, that $W$ has finite codimension in $V$, i.e. that $V/W$ is finite-dimensional).

Comment: I didn't know how to use the fact about the invariant subspace @Mohan

Comment: @JendrikStelzner In the course I'm taking we just have vector spaces such that $dim V < \infty$. How would that help solving the question ?

Answer (score 2):

Expansion of my comment/question above.

$W$ is invariant under $T$ implies, it induces a linear map $T':V/W\to V/W$. One is of course assuming that $W\neq V$, so $V/W\neq 0$ and thus $T'$ must have an eigen vector $v'\in V/W$ with $T'(v')=\lambda v'$. Lift everything to $V$, so if $v$ lifts $v'$, one has $v\not\in W$, $T(v)-\lambda v\in W$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume $V$ is of finite dimension over $\Bbb C$:

$\dim_{\Bbb C} V < \infty. \tag 0$

Since $W$ is an invariant subspace of $T$,

$T(W) \subseteq W, \tag 1$

the linear transformation $T$ factors through to a linear transformation $\tilde T$ defined on the quotient vector space $V/W$:

$\tilde T: V/W \to V/W \tag 2$

given by

$\tilde T(v + W) = T(v) + W; \tag 3$

$\tilde T$ is well-defined and depends only on the coset $v + W$, for

$v_1 + W = v_2 + W \Longleftrightarrow v_1 - v_2 \in W, \tag 4$

which implies *via* (1)

$T(v_1) - T(v_2) = T(v_1 - v_2) \in W, \tag 5$

and thus

$T(v_1) + W = T(v_2) + W, \tag 6$

that is

$\tilde T(v_1 + W) = \tilde T(v_2 + W) \tag 7$

and thus we see that $\tilde T$ is well-defined.  In light of (0),

$\dim_{\Bbb C} V/W < \infty, \tag 8$

and thus in the usual manner we infer that there exists some

$\lambda \in \Bbb C \tag 9$

and

$v \in V \setminus W \tag{10}$

with

$(\tilde T - \lambda I)(v + W) = 0 \in V/W; \tag{11}$

thus,

$(T - \lambda I)v + W = (\tilde T - \lambda I)(v + W) = 0 \in V/W, \tag{12}$

and therefore

$(T - \lambda I)v \in W; \tag{13}$

finally,

$v \notin W \tag{14}$

as indicated by (10).

Answer (score 0):

Let $dim V = n$, and $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$be eigenvalues in the field $\mathbb{C}$, where they can be equal. We go by contradiction. Suppose there is no such $v \in V$. So, for any $v \notin W$, and for any eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ we have:$ (T - \lambda I)(v) \notin W$. Since we know that minimal polynomial splits over the field, then we can say for minimal polynomial we have:

$\forall v \notin W \implies (T - \lambda_1 I)...(T-\lambda_n I) (v) \notin W \implies 0 \notin W $
Therefore, this implies $0$ is not in $W$ which is a contradiction, because $W$ is a subspace of $V$, and it must contain $0$.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{F}$? What is $U$? What is $L$? (Rhetorical questions.)

Comment: @blargoner Sorry, edited!